# How to analyse the performance? via jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am not able to judge the performance of a `random_page`, I have recorded a page and played it in JMeter.

I have set:

```
No of threads: 100
Ramp up period: 1 s
loop count: 1
```

I got the result:

```
Average: 876
Median: 694
90% Line: 1343
Throughput: 97.7 / s
```

I am new to JMeter, How to analyse the performance? What could be the target throughput for an average flow?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a better view of what's going on during your test I would recommend using:

1. [JMeter Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
2. [Extra graphs](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Graphs) provided via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project

Also if you think you have 100 concurrent users given your setup - it might not be the case. Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for detailed explanation on how does JMeter work and what [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings stand for.